# Vuetify JS 2.x card content z-index

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add some custom CSS to the `.v-responsive__content` element within the Vuetify JS card component. I've looked online and can't seem to find a slot for this, I need to set the z-index value of this element manually as I'm using a `::before` on the `v-card` component to add a background overlay.

I'm having some troubles with targeting this, can someone help/advise?

```html
<v-card
  class="mx-auto mb-8"
  max-width="375"
>
  <v-img
    class="white--text align-end"
    height="200"
    :src="source"
  >
    <v-card-title class="pb-0 mb-n1">Title</v-card-title>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="8">
        <v-card-subtitle class="white--text text-truncate py-0">Subtitle</v-card-subtitle>
      </v-col>
      <v-col class="text-right">
        <v-chip
          class="chip-custom chip-custom--primary ma-0 mr-4 mt-n2"
          color="primary"
          text-color="white"
          small
        >
          text
          <v-icon right small class="ml-1">mdi-star</v-icon>
        </v-chip>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-img>
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access it like this

1. Add custom class to vuetify component

   ```
    <v-img
    class="white--text align-end custom-image-class"
    height="200"
    :src="source">...</v-img>
   ```
2. Add Css (sccs syntax here)

   ```
    .custom-image-class{
      .v-responsive__content{
        border: 1px red solid;
      }
   }
   ```

It looks a bit weird that you want to add html content within the v-img. If you want the image as background image I would not recommend the v-img component as it is.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use inline style for z-index

Comment: Yeah, I would too, but I need to add that z-index to `v-responsive__content` which is automatically generated...